Goal-Oriented Action Planning Regression Logic Confusion
The image below shows the original example of GOAP regressive search by Dr. Jeff Orkin. It is explained that the planner searches regressively the space of actions for a sequence that will take the character from his starting state to his goal state. In each step of the regressive search, the planner tries to find an action that has an effect that will satisfy one of the unsatisfied goal conditions.
My question is as follows:
Based on the example shown in the image, the regressive search result is goal -> attack -> load weapon -> draw weapon, and when it comes to execution it goes in forward direction and becomes draw weapon -> load weapon -> attack goal. Each action from the action space only appears once. Assuming that the action space consists of [attack, load weapon, draw weapon, use potion, retreat], does the plan only represents the roadmap to achieve the goal instead of the full, complete list of actions? How does it deal with the situation for the regressive search where it requires multiple Attack actions to occur, such that the forward sequence is draw weapon -> load weapon -> attack -> attack -> attack? Or is this situation even valid in the first place?
Dr. Jeff Orkin's example of regressive search
I tried looking up on the author's publication, went through ChatGPT, Gemini, and Google Scholars for any potential answers but it doesn't seem like I found any answer to my confusion. I would appreciate the help for helping me to clear up my confusions. Thank you in advance.

Interesting question - I find GOAP is often either not discussed at all, or only at surface level.
The Problem with OG-GOAP Statevars
Jeff Orkin's original GOAP used binary state variables.
I can only guess why - it was mid-Noughties and developed for a real-time shooter AI, so performance was far more important than power, most likely. If you use binary vars, you can compress the whole state into a single bitflag integer and do bitwise ops super-fast.
In that setup, as you've noticed, 'stacking' Actions for increased effect is not straightforward (you can sort of get around the limitation using horrible, horrible hacks like cloning Actions by intensity, but... it's not a good time).
You're asking about regressive search, but it really doesn't matter - forward search has the same issues.
Building a better GOAP
However... it doesn't have to be that way! Nothing about GOAP requires an implementation to use bitflags.
What you do need is a data structure that provides key-value mappings and relatively cheap random-access reads/writes.
The lazy option here is obviously a HashMap, but if you know all your keys upfront you could just as well use structs or arrays (by mapping human-friendly keys to fixed array indices).
It's not going to be as fast as bitwise ops and we have to define a state arithmetic (although usually as simple as 'add values with the same key'), but now we're cooking with a whole range of numbers!
For instance, we can now set an AI goal to have MONEY=250 and give it one action, Work<Pre:(), Eff:(MONEY=+50,)> and it will correctly figure out the following plan: Work->Work->Work->Work->Work.
Regressing with style
For regressive search, this is particularly nice - we can define our SUCCESS state as 'no negative-valued statevars'.

We start from a blank state,
We add all initial statevars and subtract all Goal statevars from it,
We search for any Action whose Effects increase the negative-valued statevars,
We predict the new State (by adding Effects to the current state then subtracting their Preconditions)
We queue the current candidate Plan, its predicted State, and its cost in a PriorityQueue.
Once we reach a point where the State no longer has negatives (or has all zeros, if you want an exact solution), we found the best Plan that satisfies the Goal!

My assorted GOAP discoveries

I've resisted backwards-search supremacy for GOAP for some time for various semi-sensible reasons, but Jeff Orkin had it right the first time - the regressive search scheme in the previous section is about 100x-1000x faster on complex plans and still supports handling cycles.

The plan quality is also superior with regressive planning - a forward planner often winds up with entirely superfluous pointless steps if the actionspace is broad enough. Regressive search can filter out freeloaders that don't contribute to any unsettled statevar.

For... some reason, adding max queue size (i.e. turning plain AStar into a Beam Search) with a fairly low limit (depends on the actionspace, but 50 seemed like a sweet spot, but it scales with the complexity of the problem) works absolute wonders for regressive search. We're talking a 10x speedup when tuned well compared to wide/unlimited beam.



Thank you for your feedback! You have provided me with a very interesting insight on how to construct the GOAP which I struggled for some time previously, and I really appreciate that.
